# .SaveChanges() stores duplicates in entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

```
for ( int i = 0; i < libraryList.Count; i++)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        context.Library.Add(libraryList[i]);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

A library contains an entity 'predefinedgoals' which is already set up in the DB. So when the above code runs it stores dublicates of 'predefinedgoals' and assigns new ID's to them.

I read that I should attach the existing entity to the context but I'm not sure how to to do it in my scenario. The classes look like this:

```
class library
    int libraryID
    list<book> bks
```

.

```
class book
    int bookID
    list<importantdates> impdts
```

.

```
class importantdate
    int importantdateID
    predefinedgoal predfg
    int numberofresellers
```

.

```
class predefinedgoal
    int predefinedgoalID
    string description
    int daysfrompublication
```

I tried something like this right after `ModelState.IsValid` but I sense I'm doing it wrong:

```
var prdfgs= context.predefinedgoals.ToList();
foreach(var pg in prdfgs)
    context.predefinedgoals.Attach(pg);
```

Comment: Are you also creating `Book` objects along with the `Library` object, or are they already in the database?

Comment: @IronMan84 Yes every variable listed in the classes described are created and should be stored. Its only predefinedgoal that exists already so I dont need those objects saved again - just a reference to their existing ID.

Comment: Are you sure that Entity framework not only knows about the columns  but also knows that they represent primary keys, and knows about the relationship between this primary key and the foreign key in Library?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN Can I not assume that it does when the keys are named xID? The data and keys are stored exactly right except for that duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to why it stored duplicates in my scenario was that I performed tasks in two different classes - using different database context variables in each of them.

So class #1 is the one in my question, that's where I'm saving to the DB using context #1. In class #2 I retrieved all the PredefinedGoals and added them to ImportantDates but to do this I created context #2. The ID's and objects were the same but retrieved from different context variables.

I solved it by retrieving the PredefinedGoals in class #1 with context variable #1 and sent them as an argument to class #2.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is going to be based on a couple of assumptions, but I've seen this exact problem so many times that this is automatically my go-to answer.

What I think you're doing is that you're creating `Library`, `Book`, and `ImportantDate` objects (and setting up all of the relationships between them as well). In the process of doing all of this, however, you are trying to set the `PreDefinedGoal` navigational property on those `ImportantDate` objects, all the while leaving the actual `int` FK property (that would be something like `PreDefinedGoalID`), still set to 0. When that happens, Entity Framework disregards the fact that the object contained in the navigational property has an ID on it, and assumes that you are trying to create this `PreDefinedGoal` object from scratch, just like you're creating the `ImportantDate` object (as well as the others). It will then create a `PreDefinedGoal` object with the exact same data as the one you're actually trying to use, but it will create it as a separate, duplicate record in the database.

The solution to your problem then is simple: Don't set the navigational property. Just simply set the FK (`ImportantDate.PreDefinedGoalID`) to the ID of the `PreDefinedGoal` object that you want to hook up to it. When you do that, and you save it, Entity Framework will then reach out to the database for the correct object based on that ID, and thus you will avoid having duplicate `PreDefinedGoal` objects in your database.

FYI: I learned this from one of Julie Lerman's [MSDN posts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx). If you're going to be working with EF, I highly recommend reading her posts and columns.

Comment: I'm confused. `ImportantDate` doesn't contain `predefinedGoalID`. I could do this: `ImportantDate.PredefinedGoal.PredefinedGoalID = IDinDB` but it will create duplicates too, only `PredefinedGoal.description` and `PredefinedGoal.daysFromPublication` would become null.

Comment: Could you then list off every field in ImportantDates, please? You can't just have a navigational property without a FK property.

Comment: They are all listed. Do you mean I have to specify the FK in another way than just having `ImportantDate` contain a `PredefinedGoal` object (which in turn contains its own ID)?

`ImportantDate` does contain the `PredefinedGoalID` but only via the `PredefinedGoal` object. Not as a field in its class.

Comment: What exactly is the relationship between `ImportantDate` and `PreDefinedGoal`?

Comment: One `ImportantDate` can have one `PreDefinedGoal`.

Comment: No, that is it. So for each existing `PredefinedGoal` in the DB I will create one `ImportantDate` with a reference to that `PredefinedGoal`.

Answer (score 1):

I am in the same situation and found a workaround. The way this workaround works makes me think that in this case EF is to blame for handling the situation badly.

In order to simplify the example I will just post an example with one object and it's navigational property.

```
public class Topic
{
   int Id { get; set; }
   public String Name { get; set; }
   public String Description { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
   int Id { get; set; }
   public Topic Topic { get; set; }
   // additional properties don't matter now
}
```

Note the absence of any foreign key or other data annotations. EF6 will correctly create the database schema from this and infer that ***Id*** is the primary key.

Without workaround adding a new course for an existing topic will create a new topic object with a new Id (overwriting the Id it was given!) :

```
db.Courses.Add(course);
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The braindead workaround:

```
course.topic = db.Topics.Find(course.topic.Id);
db.Courses.Add(course);
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

In other words, if the topic has been loaded from the context directly, EF will recognize it as an existing topic and don't try to add it again.

Update: To just attach the entity without reloading it:

```
db.Topics.Attach(course.topic);
```

However you will run into more issues with this setup, it is probably best to use ForeignKey attribute(s) and include the TopicId in Course object. Following works OK but still looks ridiculous to me:

```
    [ForeignKey("Topic")]
    public int TopicId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TopicId")]
    public virtual Topic Topic { get; set; }
```

Would love to hear about a less redundant solution though.

Comment: Is possible to apply this technique to a one-to-many pattern? I'm trying to build upon your work but not sure it'll work quite like that... My situation would be similar to having a Course with a virtual List<Topic>